# Generating x number of pictures

Tags: image, photoshop-script

I need to generate pictures with a certain size (in pixels). Each picture will have an incrementing number in it. That is all that will be in the picture, a number. I've been thinking of using photoshop but I have no idea how the scripting works. Any suggestions or examples I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org) and its text handling feautures (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of doing that using ImageMagick:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..3}; do
   echo Generating $i...
   convert -size 256x256 xc:black \
           -gravity south -background orange -splice 0x20 -annotate +0+2 "$i" image-$i.png
done
```

And the result:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't remember why I needed this anymore, but thanks!