# Batch generate numbered images

Tags: image, batch-file

Does anybody know of any software able to automate the process of creating images with increasing numbers ? I want to generate images 1 to 20 but i want to test different sizes, different backgrounds, etc.

Comment: Example of the required process will allow a program to be devised, otherwise it's too braod a question.

Comment: it's not a broad question.. take a background picture, insert in the software how many pictures you want (1-20), set the dimensions and let it generate 20 images!

Comment: It's extremely broad. 20 images of _what_? How are all the images supposed to differ? What are backgrounds? Do you just want random dimensions? Give examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: check this (ens especially the examples): http://www.imagemagick.org/

Comment: See my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886027/generating-x-number-of-pictures/27424533#27424533